# SSTableLoader error in Cassandra 2.2.3 Too Many Open Files

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I'm currently using SSTableLoader to load data from multiple CSV files into cassandra. Previously when I ran SSTableLoader on Cassandra 2.1.9, this ran successfully without any errors.

However since I've upgraded to cassandra 2.2.3, I've been encountering the **following error from SSTableLoader:**

```
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:144) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter$1.apply(CompressedStreamWriter.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter$1.apply(CompressedStreamWriter.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.applyToChannel(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:293) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.write(CompressedStreamWriter.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:96) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:335) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToTrustedChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:579) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:140) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    ... 11 common frames omitted


After examining the system.log file in "/var/log/cassandra", I see that the error was caused by "Too many open files".

Here is the error message in the system.log file:

ERROR [STREAM-IN-/169.254.122.80] 2015-12-02 11:37:48,235 StreamSession.java:524 - [Stream #d33ca5f0-98e8-11e5-b1fd-732c31b2403a] Streaming error occurred
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/pricing/listings-088f7050945411e59780d168f1e8851b/tmp-la-968-big-Data.db: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.<init>(SequentialWriter.java:131) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.<init>(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:168) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat$WriterFactory.open(BigFormat.java:107) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:84) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:106) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:95) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReader.createWriter(StreamReader.java:129) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamReader.read(CompressedStreamReader.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:38) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:58) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:261) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Having researched through previous questions on this topic, One of the things that I have tried is to use the ulimit command to set the number of open files to 1000000. However after restarting the cassandra service, I still get the error.

Is there anything else that I need to do make these changes come into affect? Would there be a setting that I would have to set in cassandra.yaml file to prevent this from happening?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This problem comes because of the limitation of total number of open file descriptor. check this limit using command

```
ulimit -a  
or  
ulimit -n
```

Simple way to change it use command -

```
ulimit -n 100000
```

(I ran this command as root user, one can use probably sudo)

Answer (score 1):

Using ulimit probably didnt apply it the way you expected. Can check with
`cat /proc/<pid>/limits`
Configure it in your limits.conf and update other things like nproc limit while there. see http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that, I managed to solve the problem.

For other peoples information, I did the following:

1. Edit the limits.conf file in /etc/security
2. Add the following entry:

   - soft nofile 100000
   - hard nofile 100000
3. Saved the changes
4. Reboot the machine using the 'reboot' command
5. After rebooting the machine, I ran the 'ulimit -a' command saw that the number of open files is 100000.
6. The bulkloading process is successful.